# Match when an array element appears before another element (MongoDb)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The documents in my collection I have the following structure for an Order:

```
[
{
  OrderId: 'ID1',
  StatusLog: [
    {
      Timestamp: 'Some ISO Date',
      Status: 1,
      Reason: 'Because',
      User: 'User1'
    },
    {
      Timestamp: 'Some ISO Date',
      Status: 2,
      Reason: 'No Idea',
      User: 'User2'
    },
    {
      Timestamp: 'Some ISO Date',
      Status: 3,
      Reason: 'Because',
      User: 'User2'
    },
    {
      Timestamp: 'Some ISO Date',
      Status: 2 // NOTE: status can go back to 2,
      Reason: 'Some Idea',
      User: 'User1'
    }
},
{
  OrderId: 'ID2',
  StatusLog: [
    {
      Timestamp: 'Some ISO Date',
      Status: 1,
      Reason: 'Because',
      User: 'User1'
    },
    {
      Timestamp: 'Some ISO Date',
      Status: 2, 
      Reason: 'The reason to include in results',
      User: 'User2'
    },
    {
      Timestamp: 'Some ISO Date',
      Status: 3, 
      Reason: 'Because',
      User: 'User2'
    }
}
]
```

I wrote an aggregate query that will allow me to count the number of orders for every Reason+User combination.

```
    [
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: '$StatusLog'
            }
        },

        {
            $match: {
                'StatusLog.Status': 2
            }
        },

        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    'reason': '$StatusLog.Reason',
                    'user': '$StatusLog.User'
                },
                'orderCount': { $sum: 1 }
            }
        },
    ]
```

The output of the above query is in the exact format I need. However, I'm looking to add these filters to the query:

1. the order must include a StatusLog element with Status=2
2. the order must include a *previous* StatusLog element with Status=3
3. every order must only be counted once

So, from the array of sample data above, only the order with OrderId='ID1', and the result should be:

```
[
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "reason" : "The reason to include in results", 
        "user" : "User2"
    }, 
    "orderCount" : 1.0
}
]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask

Answer (score 0):

- `$unwind` deconstruct `StatusLog` array
- `$match` Status in 2 or 3
- `$group` by User and make array of `Status`, get first Reason and get `orderCount` of `Status` 2
- `$match` filter user who have Status in 2 and 3 using `$all`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$StatusLog" },
  { $match: { "StatusLog.Status": { $in: [2, 3] } } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$StatusLog.User",
      Status: { $push: "$StatusLog.Status" },
      Reason: { $first: "$StatusLog.Reason" },
      orderCount: {
        $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$StatusLog.Status", 2] }, 1, 0] }
      }
    }
  },
  { $match: { Status: { $all: [2, 3] } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UDz4UyVKVmd)